# ASP.NET CORE 3.0 Identity not working on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core

I am working with the Identity set on an ASP.NET Core 3.0 application, deployed to Ubuntu 19.04.

The Identity areas don't seem to be working correctly. When I navigate to it, it gives me a 'not found' from Nginx. I am trying to figure what I need to change to get Nginx to allow the Identity area (and other areas) through the reverse proxy. When I curl localhost:5000/Identity/Account/Register, I receive HTML.

Nginx setup:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/jl3/linux-x64/publish/;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {


        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location /css/ {
        root /var/www/jl3/linux-x64/publish/wwwroot;
    }
    location /images/ {
        root /var/www/jl3/linux-x64/publish/wwwroot;
    }
    location /js/ {
        root /var/www/jl3/linux-x64/publish/wwwroot;
    }
    location /lib/ {
        root /var/www/jl3/linux-x64/publish/wwwroot;
    }

}
```

Am I missing a location reference, or is my root command incorrect? The main (not Identity) page works fine, but for a few other pages, I had to include Hrefs instead of using asp-controller and asp-action helper tags.